# What am I doing wrong in handling this Scala collection?

Tags: scala, collections

Given a List[CaseClass] I want to group the elements by two class attributes and get nested Maps

```
case class CaseClass(
   a   String,
   b   String,
   c   String
)

val collection: List[CaseClass] = List(
   CaseClass("a1","b1","c1"),
   CaseClass("a1","b1","c2"),
   CaseClass("a1","b2","c3"),
   CaseClass("a2","b2","c4"),
   CaseClass("a2","b2","c5"),
)
val res = collection.groupBy(_.a).map{ case (k,v) => v.groupBy(_.b)}
```

What I get is Map[String, CaseClass] object grouped by "b" attribute. But I want to get Map[String, Map[String, CaseClass]] grouped by "a" (external Map) and "b" (internal Map) like this:

```
Map("a1" -> 
         Map("b1" -> List( CaseClass("a1","b1","c1"),
                           CaseClass("a1","b1","c2"))), 
         Map("b2" -> List( CaseClass("a1","b2","c3"))), 
    "a2" -> 
         Map("b2" -> List( CaseClass("a2","b2","c4"),
                           CaseClass("a2","b2","c5"))))
```

How should I change my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `(k,v) => v.groupBy(_.b)` needs to map `(key, value)` to `(key, value)`, but this is mapping `(key, value)` to `value`. The keys are getting discarded.

So you just need to preserve the keys:

```
val res = collection.groupBy(_.a).map{ case (k,v) => (k, v.groupBy(_.b)) }
```

Comment: Ouch!! It was so simple! Thanx